# Проверка переменной на соответствие диапазону

Tags: python, переменные

Допустим, есть входные данные: четыре числа от 1 до 8 каждое. Как сделать проверку каждого числа на соответствие заданному диапазону?

Я сделал вот такую запись, но она просто огромная: вдруг будет var_with_long_name или просто много переменных. Как сократить эту запись?

```
a, b, c, d = int(input()), int(input()), int(input()), int(input())

if a < 1 or a > 8 or b < 1 or b > 8 or c < 1 or c > 8 or d < 1 or d > 8:
    print('Еррор')
else:
    print('Не еррор, идём работать дальше')
```

Comment: Что такое var_with_long_name ?

Comment: Возможное имя переменной.

Comment: Блин, все решения очень интересные, спасибо всем большое. Я хотел как просто увидеть сокращённую запись своего варианта, так и интересные способы типа перемещения переменных в список, использования новых для меня функций и т. д. Это был мой первый вопрос на stackoverflow, от которого я получил столько знаний, сколько я наверное не получал за последний месяц. Я, конечно, неактивно обучаюсь, но stackoverflow на русском мотивирует заниматься.
Ещё раз, этим комментарием хочу поблагодарить КАЖДОГО, кто ответил.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

способ 1:

использовать:

```
1 <= value <= 8
```

если много переменных, то можно использовать функцию `all`

функция `all` выдает `True` если верны все значения иначе `False`

```
a = 5
b = 3
c = 4

print(all(map(lambda i: 1 <= i <= 8, (a, b, c))))
```

способ 2: использовать `range` для задания диапазона и ключевое слово `in` для проверки

```
all(map(lambda i: i in range(1, 9), (a, b, c)))
```

способ 3: это модификация способа 2, которая позволяет работать с любыми числами:

```
all(map(lambda i: i in (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8), (a, b, c)))
```

например, если надо было бы проверить диапазоны от 1 до 3 и от 6 до 8, то было бы

```
all(map(lambda i: i in (1, 2, 3, 6, 7, 8), (a, b, c)))
```

**P.S.**

вместо `map` можно использовать более короткую запись с `for`:

```
all(1 <= i <= 8 for i in (a, b, c))
```

или

```
all(i in range(1, 9) for i in (a, b, c))
```

Comment: лучшим является вариант из  P.S.

Answer (score 1):

Универсально:

```
range_ = range(1, 9)
for x in map(int, input().split()):
    if x not in range_:
        print('Error')
        break
else:
    print('Succes')
```

Answer (score 1):

мне кажется переменные лучше положить в список

```
a, b, c, d = int(input()), int(input()), int(input()), int(input())

arr = [a, b, c d]

if 1 <= min(arr) and max(arr) <= 9:
    print('Еррор')
else:
    print('Не еррор, идём работать дальше')
```

Answer (score 0):

Вот для любого количества вводимых данных

```
cont = True
while cont is True:
    v = int(input())
    if 1 <= v <= 8:
        print("Не еррор, идём работать дальше")
    else:
        print("Еррор")
        cont = False
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if 1 <= a <= 8 and 1 <= b <= 8 and 1 <= c <= 8 and 1 <= d <= 8:
    print('Не еррор, идём работать дальше')
```

Comment: Ужас, конечно...